# Lightning - onChange issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, issue, onchange

**Component code:**

```
<lightning:select name="wallheight" label="Wall Height : " onchange="{!c.doSomething}">            
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.wallheight}" var="wallheight">  
        <option text="{!wallheight.Name}" value="{!wallheight.value}" selected="{!wallheight.selected}"/>                   
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

**Controller code:**

```
doSomething : function(component,event,helper){
    console.log(component.find("wallheight").get("v.value"));        
   //alert(x);
}
```

I am getting below error

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action
>   failed: c:form$controller$doSomething [Cannot read property 'get' of
>   undefined] Failing descriptor: {c:form$controller$doSomething}

Comment: It seems that your JavaScript controller was not able to find the wallheight variable from component. That is the reason it throws error as cannot read something of undefined

Comment: What if you add aura:id to the select

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `aura:id` instead of `name`.

Try this :

```
<lightning:select aura:id="wallheight" label="Wall Height : " onchange="{!c.doSomething}">            
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.wallheight}" var="wallheight">  
        <option text="{!wallheight.Name}" value="{!wallheight.value}" selected="{!wallheight.selected}"/>                   
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```